# how to customize paypal popup window css

Tags: css, paypal, integration

i'm trying to customize paypal popup window css, but I don't know how to do it.

There are two things I want to change:

1) remove the underscore (e.g. item2.  I found that paypal randomly add underscore to checkout page items though i just pass item name to paypal)

2) enlarge the item display area. Now, paypal popup window only display maximum 2 items. If i have more than two, i have to scroll down. But user may not notice the scroll down bar.

Is there a way to override paypal popup css? Thanks

[image]

Comment: If the code is not in an iframe you should be able to override with specificity or !important. Got a demo?

Comment: Inspect the element in browser and see in which input type it generates. Then apply the desired css class to that element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure which of PayPal's services uses a popup. You sure you're integrating properly? In any event, you're loading this page from PayPal and could only possibly attach custom styles to it by manipulating the popup window's DOM from the parent window once you've detected a pageload. Hardly foolproof, and maybe not even possible. Best bet is to just take advantage of what customization options PayPal gives you in your profile settings and get "close enough."